# Socket Server channel for specific users

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, sockets, redis

I wrote a Little laravel / JavaScript app, in which I can notify users. Currently all users are notified but I want to notify specific users.

so far I built this:

Laravel Event class:

```
class NotificationSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $notifications;
    public $user;

    public function __construct(array $notifications, $user)
    {
        $this->notifications = $notifications;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['notification-channel'];
        // return ['notification-channel-'. $this->user->id];
    }
}
```

And I fire the Event like this,

```
# fire event to sent notification
event(new NotificationSent(
    $notifications, $admin
));
```

I want to fire the Event on the user ($admin contains a user model).

My socket Server socket.js

```
// socket.js
var server = require('http').Server();

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

// class declaration
var Redis = require('ioredis');

// Redis UserSignedUp Channel
var redisUserSignedUp = new Redis();


// Redis NotificationSent Channel
var redisNotificationSent = new Redis();

redisNotificationSent.subscribe('notification-channel');

redisNotificationSent.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    console.log(channel, message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

server.listen(3000);
```

And my Event.js

```
var socket = io('http://192.168.3.125:3000'); // local

Vue.use(VToaster, {timeout: 5000})

new Vue({

    el: '#app',

    data: {
        authID: $('#auth-id').val(),
    },

    mounted: function() {

        // NotificationSent Event
        socket.on('notification-channel-' + this.authID + ':App\\Events\\NotificationSent', function(data) {
        // socket.on('notification-channel:App\\Events\\NotificationSent', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            this.$toaster.info('Hi.');
        }.bind(this));
    },


});
```

Comment: send user_id in message.data and match user_id before showing notification on screen

Comment: @VikashAmbani I can get the user id and check that in my Event.js but I can not use the user id in my socket.js (Server)

Comment: why to you append this `':App\\Events\\NotificationSent'`? The channel name string should be same in the php broadcast and the js subscribe. To make it user specific do as you have shown by appending just the user id

Comment: @MikeMiller but I can not subscribe in my socket.js to that channel dynamically, for test purpose I just added the string like this `redisNotificationSent.subscribe('notification-channel-1');
` and it worked but it is not dynamic

Comment: @Jaan so you need to get the user id then. This is the only way. Without more info on your app its hard to advise but you might make another network request in socket.js to get it from the server or you could retrieve from localStorage

Comment: @MikeMiller I am not sure what further Information you Need, it is a laravel application and I implemented redis + nodejs + socketio. I created an EventClass with a channel and I am trying to sent "notifications" using the socket, which works fine, but they are shown right now to all users.

Comment: @Jaan I dont need any more. I am not going over your entire app code. But its impossible to know what solution is appropriate based on the above. You  need to figure out how to get the user id into socket.js. I gave you 2 options but there is probably others you could explore